# making a new column with 3 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose there are 3 columns as

```
           duration       mode        fare
              34            2          0
               20           1          0
              15            4          1
              10            2          0
               3            4          1.3
```

I need a new column which is as follow

```
    If mode=1  is 0

   If mode=2 is duration*0.07

   If mode=4 is equal fare
```

output

```
           duration       mode        fare      cost
              34            2          0         34*0.07
               20           1          0         0
              15            4          1         1
              10            2          0         10*0.07
               3            4          1.3       1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package, but regular `ifelse` from base R can also work here:

```
df$cost <- ifelse(df$mode == 1, 0, ifelse(df$mode == 2, df$duration*0.07, df$fare))
```

This assumes that the only `mode` values would be 1, 2, and 4, and so the bucket `else` condition would only be including `mode = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the input `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, here is a one-liner in base R.  `mode == 2` is converted from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 and similarly for `mode == 4`.

```
transform(DF, cost = (mode == 2) * duration * 0.07 + (mode == 4) * fare)
```

giving:

```
  duration mode fare cost
1       34    2  0.0 2.38
2       20    1  0.0 0.00
3       15    4  1.0 1.00
4       10    2  0.0 0.70
5        3    4  1.3 1.30
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "         duration       mode        fare
              34            2          0
               20           1          0
              15            4          1
              10            2          0
               3            4          1.3"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just translate your conditions into a `case_when` statement in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cost = case_when(mode == 1 ~0, 
                          mode == 2 ~ duration * 0.07, 
                          mode == 4 ~ fare, 
                          TRUE ~ NA_real_))

#  duration mode fare cost
#1       34    2  0.0 2.38
#2       20    1  0.0 0.00
#3       15    4  1.0 1.00
#4       10    2  0.0 0.70
#5        3    4  1.3 1.30
```

Or a nested `ifelse` condition

```
df$cost <- with(df, ifelse(mode == 1, 0, 
                       ifelse(mode == 2, duration * 0.07,
                          ifelse(mode == 4, fare, NA))))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(duration = c(34L, 20L, 15L, 10L, 3L), mode = c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 4L), fare = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1.3)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: The `ifelse` option was given by another user before you edited your answer with it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I didn't saw your answer while updating my answer. I guess the same happened with the `case_when` option as well.